# Azure Devops Git branch case sensitivity

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

When I view my branches through the Azure Devops portal I notice that I have the following;

```
feature/feature1  
Feature/feature2
```

Locally through my git client (Fork) it looks correct;

```
feature/feature1  
       /feature2
```

How do I correct this on Azure devops and is there a way I can prevent this from occurring in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a setting called "**Case enforcement**" (*Project Settings -> Repositories -> Policies*) that at least prevents case-sensitivity conflicts:

[image]

I doubt you can enforce a lowercase branch name with Azure DevOps right now - at least from the UI. However, you might be able to do this using the [tf command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/require-branch-folders?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser).

To correct your branch name, just create another branch based on your initial branch (ensure you have commited all your local changes) and then delete the initial branch.