# 'git pull' pulls the same data over again

Tags: git

My local `master` pulls some branches (always the same) every time I call `git pull`. After those pulls I tried `git pull origin master` which fetched the origin master data and when I tried it again I got `Already up to date`, which was expected. But when I tried `git pull` again I keep getting the same branches creations.
I thought that this might be caused by mismatch of masters in origin and local so I did `git reset --hard origin/master` and `git pull origin master`, the result `Already up to date`. Then I tried again `git pull` and I'm getting those branches again.

After calling `git pull` I see:

```
 * [new branch]          users/aaa -> origin/users/aaa
 * [new branch]          users/bbb -> origin/users/bbb
 * [new branch]          users/ccc -> origin/users/ccc
...
error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/users/ddd': is at 'hash1' but expected 'hash2'
...
 * [new branch]          users/eee -> origin/users/eee
...
! e7b282a57..aa76491e2  users/fff -> origin/users/fff  (unable to update local ref)
...
```

When calling `git fetch --prune` I got exactly the same result except I have also deletions at the top:

```
 - [deleted]             (none)     -> origin/Users/ggg/feat1
 - [deleted]             (none)     -> origin/Users/ggg/feat2
 - [deleted]             (none)     -> origin/Users/ggg/feat3
...(git pull result)
```

Scenarios I tried:

- `git pull origin master` - `Already up to date`
- `git pull` - pulls the same branches every time I call it
- `git reset --hard origin/master` -> `git pull` - pulls the same branches every time I call it
- `git fetch` - same result as `git pull`
- `get fetch --prune` - pulls the same branches and removes the same branches everytime I call it
- `git merge` - `Already up to date`
- `git branch –set-upstream-to=origin/master master` -> `git pull` - same as normal `git pull`

I want to call `git pull` to have the same result as `git pull origin master` and not fetch the same data over and over again.

Can anyone explain what might be the issue here?

(If anyone wants me to add a test scenario to check the result I will add it)

Comment: There are a lot of branches that are being added. And after the `git fetch --prune` I'm having a lot of branches being deleted as well as added. `git fetch --prune` also creates the same results over and over again. Sample part result: 
`
- [deleted]             (none)     -> origin/a
 - [deleted]             (none)     -> origin/b
 - [deleted]             (none)     -> origin/c
* [new branch]          users/f
 * [new branch]          users/g
 * [new branch]          users/h
 * [new branch]          users/j
`

Comment: @matt I made a mistake. The `git fetch --prune` with `git pull`. The latter only add branches every time I call it. I will update the post

Comment: @matt git does not say much when I call `git pull`. Mostly `* [new branch] ...`, sometimes `error: cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/users/ccc/local': is at 'hash1' but expected 'hash2'` and sometimes `! 84df8f681..bb745e318  users/ccc/local    -> origin/users/ccc/local  (unable to update local ref)` But it is still around updating the branches and adding new.

Comment: @matt I hope it's more readable right now

Comment: Are you on Windows (or a case-insensitive filesystem)? Are you literally getting output that contains both `origin/Users` and `origin/users` (note case change)?

Comment: Those are just branch names. It seems that there was such policy in version control branch naming strategy and some people were creating `users` folder and some `Users`. Strangely in Azure DevOps I cannot see folder with capitol `Users` in list of branches

Comment: @matt did those commands. I will update the post in some time. In short those errors disappear after the commands in this article and direct call `git pull` but when I call `git pull` again errors are shown again. Anything else is the same (scenarios I listed and results)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[nneoneo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1204143/nneonneo) has, in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71417298/git-pull-pulls-the-same-data-over-again#comment126234743_71417298), the right question:

> Are you on Windows (or a case-insensitive filesystem)? Are you literally getting output that contains both `origin/Users` and `origin/users` (note case change)?

Git itself *tries* to be completely case sensitive.  This means that one can create a branch named `fool` and a *second* branch named `Fool` and a third one named `fooL` and a fourth one named `FOoL` and so on.  On a Linux system, for instance, this all works just fine.  It works on Linux servers.  It even *sometimes* works, *sort of*, on your standard Windows or macOS system that is set up to be case *in*-sensitive, where if you create a file or folder named `users`, any attempt to *refer* to a file or folder named `Users` after this actually refers to the existing `users`, and vice versa.  That is, if two name components appear the same *after* case folding, the file or folder is *created* with whichever case you ask for at that time, and from then on, you *cannot get the other spelling*.

Git currently<sup>1</sup> *stores* branch, tag, and other names<sup>2</sup> in two different places, at various times:

- A branch name may appear as a single line entry in `.git/packed-refs` (the line contains the branch name and the hash ID).
- The name may be turned into a file name and stored in the `.git` directory *as* an OS-provided file: for instance, branch `main`'s hash ID value might be stored in `.git/refs/heads/main`.

If *both* names exist, Git has the OS-provided file entry override, so that if we have a `.git/packed-refs` containing the line:

```
dcc0cd074f0c639a0df20461a301af6d45bd582e refs/heads/master
```

*and* a `.git/refs/heads/main` containing some other hash ID, the other hash ID is the hash ID that your branch `main` means.

Now, suppose that the source repository you're cloning and then later using with `git fetch` has at some point a branch named `users/joe` and *a different branch* named `Users/joe`.  That source repository is stored on a Linux system, or perhaps by chance is always using the `packed-refs` file.

When you run `git clone` or `git fetch`, your own Git repository may create or update `.git/refs/remotes/users/joe` and/or `.git/refs/remotes/Users/joe`.  If you are on a Linux system yourself, this will work just fine: you now have two different remote-tracking names for the two different branch names.  But if you're using a case-insensitive macOS or Windows volume, and your Git software *tries* to do this, it will create just one of the two names, and then *re-use the existing file* for the other name.

This is exactly the scenario that gives rise to your problem.  If your Git repository has only *packed* refs, things will work.  If the upstream repository **first fixes the case mix-ups** so that *all* names are `users/<name>` and you use `git pack-refs --all` to pack all your refs, get rid of the contents of `.git/refs` to clean out any leftover trash, and then run `git fetch --prune`, the problem will go away.  But the first step is to fix the upstream repository over at `origin`.

> It seems that there was such policy in version control branch naming strategy and some people were creating `users` folder and some `Users`.

They need to stop doing that.

> Strangely in Azure DevOps I cannot see folder with [capital-U] `Users` in list of branches ...

Azure DevOps has an add-on, not part of standard (C) Git, for dealing with related case issues.  See, e.g., [Azure Devops Git branch case sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63225024/1256452) (which is about *file* name case issues).  For *branch and tag name issues* see also [the Azure online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/case-sensitivity?view=azure-devops).

---

<sup>1</sup>There is ongoing work to fix this, but it's not available in plain Git yet.  Once it is, switching to the "reftables" back end will make this problem go away.

<sup>2</sup>All of these names in Git coexist by virtue of [namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace).  A *branch* name is any name that starts with `refs/heads/`: for instance, branch `main` is really `refs/heads/main`.  A *tag* name is any name that starts with `refs/tags/`: for instance, tag `v2.1` is really `refs/tags/v2.1`.  A *remote-tracking name*—a name where your own Git stores its renamed variant of some other Git repository's *branch* name—begins with `refs/remotes/` and goes on to include the name of the remote, hence `refs/remotes/origin/` for remote `origin`.  After that comes the *branch* name as seen on the remote, i.e., the name with `refs/heads/` stripped.  This is how some other Git repository's `main` winds up stored in *your* Git repository as `refs/remotes/origin/main`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunatelly I cannot apply the fix right away because I don't the permissions to remove those branches and some of those are 1year old. Got a question though. Why do I fetch those branches over again, especially those `users/<name>`. They are lower case so I should fetch them once, right?

Comment: @Pawel: trace for yourself what happens when your own Git software creates—or tries to create—`users/bob` *after first creating* `Users/alice` (within `refs/remotes/origin`). What file name do you get? Is it `refs/remotes/origin/users/bob`, or is it `refs/remotes/origin/Users/bob`? Now, whichever name actually *does* get used, what remote-tracking name do you have in your own repository?

Comment: Note that you do not have to remove a `Users/alice` branch entirely if you have permission on the server to *rename* it to `users/alice` or perhaps `users/big-alice` if there is already also a `users/alice`. The idea here is to force all names to a single case (lowercase is generally wisest) so that the case-folding issues goes away.