# How to request GetItemContentAsync with case insensitive

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a need to request

```
GetItemContentAsync(project: this.ProjectName,
                    repositoryId: repository,
                    path: path,
                    versionDescriptor: gitVersionDescriptor));

gitVersionDescriptor = new gitVersionDescriptor { 
   VersionType = GitVersionType.Branch, 
   Version = branch 
};
```

Could I request this method to ignore casing? For example, the remote branch is `refs/head/Test`, and the `Version` I use is `refs/head/test`?

I test in my local machine, it always reports an exception:

> "System.ApplicationException: 'Unable to find branch".

As I know ADO is case insensitive by default, see: [Azure Devops Git branch case sensitivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63225024/azure-devops-git-branch-case-sensitivity)

Answer (score 1):

The policy you referenced works in a different way. According to its description, it:

> avoids case-sensitivity problems by blocking pushes that change casing.

That is if your branch was initially pushed as `refs/head/Test`, you have to request it as `refs/head/Test`. In this case, it stays case-sensitive and correctly reports that it can't find the branch `refs/head/test`.

As long as the API works on top of that, I doubt there's a way to work it around - you have to request the branch by its proper name.